# Splitting a line array into words

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array which consists of a line of words (I got using fgets). I now want to create a new array as part of the same struct that contains the same lines, but split into words that only have alphanumeric characters (so that line[1].word_in[3] would give me the 3rd word in line 1). I've had a bit of an attempt, but it has not worked.

```
    typedef struct {
        char linewords[101];
        char separateword[101];
    } line;

    line linenum[101];

    while fgets(linenum[i].linewords, 101, stdin) != NULL) {
        i++
        linenum[i].separateword = linenum[i].linewords.Split(' ');
        if (isalnum(int linenum[i].separateword) != 0) {
            /* need to remove that character */
        }
    }
```

I apologise for really having no idea what I'm doing. My first issue is obviously in splitting the struct, as this is giving me an error. Thank you

Edit:
I've added in what I'm now doing; however I am receiving assignment errors when assigning var.

```
    typedef struct {
        char linewords[101];
        char separateword[101];
    } line;

    line linenum[101];
    char var[101]
    char *strtok(char *str, const char delim);

    while fgets(linenum[i].linewords, 101, stdin) != NULL) {

        char* strcopy();
        char* strtok();
        strcpy(linenum[i].separateword,linenum[i].linewords);
        strtok(linenum[i].separateword, ' '); /*this line causes seg fault*/
        i++
        }
    }
```

Comment: what did you meant by it has not worked ?

Comment: I am getting the following error: "request for member ‘Split’ in something not a structure or union".

Comment: `linenum[i].linewords.Split(' ')` You can't make up syntax like that. If you intend to use C, then learn about C, you can't expect anything that's working in one language magically works in another language.

Comment: C doesn't have a function .Split like c# just try something different.

Comment: Is there another way of splitting the struct? I just tried giving linenum[i].linewords a variable name and splitting that and it has just given me an error.

eg. var = linenum[i].linewords;
    var.Split(' ');

Comment: You didn't got what I said. Whether it's a variable or a child of structure, you still can't use "var.split". C doesn't allow that.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for that (I was googling to find something to split and must have forgot to specify language!). So if I am trying to separate something in C based would strtok() work?

Comment: Now you are getting somewhere. Try `strtok`.

Comment: Yeah..... That'll do.....

Comment: var = linenum[i].linewords;    I'm having a bit of difficulty in specifying the string I want to split. I tried assigning it to var, but am getting errors in my assignment. The declaration for var is: char* var[101]

Comment: var should be char var[101]. not char *var[101]

Comment: It still says that the assignment types are invalid for var = linenum[i].linewords; I thought that the type for var would be char* because looking at inputs for strtok the string is meant to be char*, but even since changing var to to char, it gives me the same error for this line?

Comment: You can't assign arrays like that in C, you have to copy them. I think you need to spend some more time with the basics. And what is `char *strtok(char *str, const char delim);` doing there? You can't just paste a function prototype into your code and hope it'll magically make your program work.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Oops that wasn't meant to be there! That was supposed to be commented out!! Thanks for pointing that out. I had it there to remind me of how strtok worked. I'll give copying a go and let you know how I go. Thank you

Comment: @PaulGriffiths So I've edited the second code to match what I've done now. Thanks for teaching me to copy arrays - that's really useful!I'm now getting a segmentation fault (11) using strtok. Do you know why/how to combat this? Thanks

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Don't worry! Just figured it out. I was using single quotes instead of double! It's giving me the same string without spaces, like wanted, but I was wondering if i could store each word in a separate position in the array. Can I do this?

Comment: @KittiCat: You can't store each word in *a* separate position in the array, because each separate position is a single character, and most words have more characters than this.

Comment: What would be the best way of storing words then? Could I put the string into an array and separate each word with a null byte?

Answer (score 0):

strtok() return a character pointer. It is in

```
char *strtok(char *s, const char *delim) ;
```

So the problem is you are not saving the returned value.

```
while fgets(linenum[i].linewords, 101, stdin) != NULL) {

        //strcpy(linenum[i].separateword,linenum[i].linewords);
        linenum[i].seperatewords=strtok(linenum[i].linewords, ' ');
        i++
        }
```

It will solve your problem. 
For more details about strtok() : 
[strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strtok.htm)